# Obfuscated Proguard output jar file displays a blank window & not the complete GUI

Tags: javafx, proguard

I'm trying to obfuscate a javafx project using Proguard, this is meant to be a standalone desktop application.

**Problem** :
On executing the output jar file only a blank window appears as opposed to the complete GUI.The output from the jar is here. [screenshot - obfuscated jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr6YD.jpg)

Image of project structure with dependencies (implementations, extensions) for your [reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUcAi.jpg)

Proguard config settings (generated with ProGuard GUI) are as follows:

```
-injars 'C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp10Feb\dist\MyApp10Feb _obfusInput.jar'
-outjars 'C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyApp10Feb\dist\MyApp10Feb _obfusOutput.jar'

-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\rt.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jfr.jar'
-libraryjars 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar'
-libraryjars 'E:\Berky\Jar Files\Jars required for project\apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar'
-libraryjars 'E:\Berky\Jar Files\Jars required for project\apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar'
-libraryjars 'E:\Berky\Jar Files\Jars required for project\commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar'
-libraryjars 'E:\Berky\Jar Files\Jars required for project\groovy-all-2.0.1.jar'
-libraryjars 'E:\Berky\Jar Files\Jars required for project\h2-1.4.193.jar'
-libraryjars 'E:\Berky\Jar Files\Jars required for project\iText-2.1.7.js2.jar'
-libraryjars 'E:\Berky\Jar Files\Jars required for project\jasperreports-5.6.0.jar'

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-allowaccessmodification
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-repackageclasses p
-printmapping 'C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\ProjectWork\TestFolder\MyApp10Feb_proguard.txt'

-keepattributes javafx.fxml.FXML,Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,LocalVariable*Table,*Annotation*,Synthetic,EnclosingMethod
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.fxml,**.properties,META-INF/MANIFEST.MF,images/*.jar,publicCerts.store,production.version

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @javafx.fxml.FXML 
    <fields>;
   @javafx.fxml.FXML
   <methods>;
}

 -keep class * extends com.myapp.Test,com.myapp.ScreensController,com.myapp.report.PrintReport{
  public *;
 }

# Keep - Applications. Keep all application classes, along with their 'main'
# methods.
-keepclasseswithmembers public class com.javafx.main.Main,com.myApp.Test {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}
```

Could someone please suggest what changes are to be made to get the obfuscated jar file working correctly? Thank you for your attention to this.

Comment: You might want to check this project for reference: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it/08-build-with-proguard

Comment: I have used the proguard.conf file from your gist for reference, the output however remains the same -ie displays a blank window. :) Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try to create some MCVE to reproduce this? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve